# Randomly selecting samples

Tags: r, random

I would like to select by chance `x` samples (where `x == 2`) is my dataframe `df`:

```
sample_id           no                 State  NLABfather
NE001      chr7-42751387-42759372-1n    1n       <NA>
NE001    chr4-106417821-106429609-3n    3n       <NA>
NE002       chr28-2568550-2572925-3n    3n       <NA>
NE002     chr23-27707672-27707672-3n    3n       <NA>
NE003       chr25-1157646-1170719-1n    1n       <NA>
NE003     chr21-20145005-20155775-0n    0n       <NA>
```

Is this example the output could select `NE001` and `NE002` by chance, then:

```
sample_id           no                 State  NLABfather
NE001      chr7-42751387-42759372-1n    1n       <NA>
NE001    chr4-106417821-106429609-3n    3n       <NA>
NE002       chr28-2568550-2572925-3n    3n       <NA>
NE002     chr23-27707672-27707672-3n    3n       <NA>
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `subset(df, sample_id %in% sample(unique(sample_id),2))`?

Answer (score 1):

Or without the subset function you could do:
df[sample(c(1:nrow(df)), 2),]